# "this" gives me an error in fragment

Tags: java, android

Why does `this` give me an error in the below fragment?

This is my code:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);
```

Comment: is the class that this line of code in of type `Context` because if not, then you can't use just `this`

Comment: in any case, which is the error? please be more specific.

Comment: Activities are a Context object. Fragments are not.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);
```

- `getContext()` was added only on API 23 and should work only with few devices (since Android M still does not have a huge market share).
- `getActivity()` was added on API 11 and it is NOT deprecated.. So, you can use it.

Comment: `getContext()` exists in `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, so there is no any issues here.

Comment: Assuming he is using support Fragment which may not be always the case

Comment: Yep, but I think it almost impossible and it's even bad idea to not use support library in current circumstances

Answer (score 0):

Replace `this` with `this.getContext()` or even simply just `getContext()`

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), 
                                   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);
```

The reason being is that the constructor for an `ArrayAdapter` object looks like this,

> From https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html,
>
> ```
> ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, T[] objects)
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<T> objects)
> ```

What was probably happening before is that the class that the line of code was in was most likely not of type `Context`; therefore, you can't use `this` alone as a parameter in the construction of an ArrayAdapter. If `getContext()` doesn't work, then I'd suggest trying `getActivity()` or `getApplicationContext()` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getActivity()` which return the context of the activity that the fragment is associated with.

So your code becomes

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);`]
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` instead of using just `this` in fragment.

Comment: Only if the Fragment is a nested class